# Failed to start Docker Container Engine

Tags: debian, docker

I did a docker installation on a Debian 10.

```
sudo apt -y install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

when I want to start my Docker process I have this error message

```
systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.524903928+02:00" level=warning msg="The "graph" config file option is deprecated. Please use "data-root" instead."
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.525012262+02:00" level=info msg="Starting up"
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.527365687+02:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: "unix"" module=grpc
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.527633438+02:00" level=info msg="scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.527755361+02:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0 }] }" module=grpc
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.527880961+02:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"" module=grpc
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.529081374+02:00" level=info msg="parsed scheme: "unix"" module=grpc
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.529230177+02:00" level=info msg="scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme" module=grpc
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.529333871+02:00" level=info msg="ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0 }] }" module=grpc
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.529441750+02:00" level=info msg="ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"" module=grpc
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.530080352+02:00" level=warning msg="[graphdriver] WARNING: the overlay storage-driver is deprecated, and will be removed in a future release"
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.559185784+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support swap memory limit"
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.559471255+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt period"
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.559633433+02:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtime"
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.559978079+02:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
dockerd[55552]: time="2020-09-02T10:20:21.689312823+02:00" level=info msg="stopping event stream following graceful shutdown" error="" module=libcontainerd namespace=moby
dockerd[55552]: failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: list bridge addresses failed: PredefinedLocalScopeDefaultNetworks List: [172.17.0.0/16 172.18.0.0/16 172.19.0.0/16 172.20.0.0/16 172.21.0.0/16 172.22.0.0/16 172.23.0.0/16 172.24.0.0/16 172.25.0.0/16 172.26.0.0/16 172.27.0.0/16 172.28.0.0/16 172.29.0.0/16 172.30.0.0/16 172.31.0.0/16 192.168.0.0/20 192.168.16.0/20 192.168.32.0/20 192.168.48.0/20 192.168.64.0/20 192.168.80.0/20 192.168.96.0/20 192.168.112.0/20 192.168.128.0/20 192.168.144.0/20 192.168.160.0/20 192.168.176.0/20 192.168.192.0/20 192.168.208.0/20 192.168.224.0/20 192.168.240.0/20]: no available network
systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
systemd[1]: docker.service: Service RestartSec=2s expired, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.
systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container Engine.
```

Answer (score 1):

- Edit /lib/systemd/system/docker.service before start Docker. Add `--bip "192.168.1.1/24"` at the end of line `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd`.
- `systemctl daemon-reload`
- `systemctl start docker`