# dockerd failed to start daemon: list bridge addresses failed

Tags: networking, docker, bridge, start-stop-daemon

Exacactly the same issue as [Failed to start Docker Container Engine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607477/failed-to-start-docker-container-engin), as I'm getting `dockerd failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: list bridge addresses failed: PredefinedLocalScopeDefaultNetworks List no available network`:

```
$ journalctl -xeu docker.service | grep 'failed to start daemon'
Nov 23 21:56:08 myhost dockerd[525139]: failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: list bridge addresses failed: PredefinedLocalScopeDefaultNetworks List: [172.17.0.0/16 172.18.0.0/16 172.19.0.0/16 172.20.0.0/16 172.21.0.0/16 172.22.0.0/16 172.23.0.0/16 172.24.0.0/16 172.25.0.0/16 172.26.0.0/16 172.27.0.0/16 172.28.0.0/16 172.29.0.0/16 172.30.0.0/16 172.31.0.0/16 192.168.0.0/20 192.168.16.0/20 192.168.32.0/20 192.168.48.0/20 192.168.64.0/20 192.168.80.0/20 192.168.96.0/20 192.168.112.0/20 192.168.128.0/20 192.168.144.0/20 192.168.160.0/20 192.168.176.0/20 192.168.192.0/20 192.168.208.0/20 192.168.224.0/20 192.168.240.0/20]: no available network
```

But that solution doesn't work for me.

And I've found out the reason is that there is no `--bip` flag any more to docker:

```
/usr/bin/docker daemon --debug --bip=192.168.0.0/20
unknown flag: --bip
See 'docker --help'.
```

What I [found](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/123) works is:

```
 ip link add name docker0 type bridge
 ip addr add dev docker0 172.17.0.1/16
 systemctl daemon-reload
 systemctl start docker
```

However, I believe such change won't be persistent over reboot, thus need a permanent solution.

Comment: I had the problem on an Ubuntu 20.04-based Linux distro and it sort of… went away by itself after I manually added the `docker0` link. Subsequent `systemctl restart docker`s just worked, even if I deleted the link. So I dunno. I don't claim to understand what to put in the `daemon.json` config file, but you may find more useful context in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/123).